# Site down issue when running enlightn in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, phpstan

I am trying to run the Enlightn package on my Laravel application using the following command:

```
php artisan enlightn
```

It is executing properly; however, it significantly slows down my application and sometimes even causes it to go down. After investigating, I noticed that Enlightn consumes a large amount of server memory during its execution. I checked the memory usage using the command `free -m`.

Could anyone kindly assist me with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried limiting memory consumption when executing; or increasing AWS instance type? `php -d memory_limit=512M artisan enlightn` How much memory do you have; how much is it consuming? Do you have swap enabled?

Comment: Yes. i have tried using memory limit but not worked. I have 4GB memory. swap is not enabled.